# Set default value of dropdown list on another page equal to value selected on previous page

Tags: php

I have the following code that generates a dropdown list.  I want the value selected to be the default value of the same drop-down list on another page.  The code I am using to generate the drop-down list is `area_index.php`:

```
// Write out our query.
    $query = "SELECT * FROM hub";
    // Execute it, or return the error message if there's a problem.
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    $dropdown = "<select name='hub'>";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $dropdown .= "\r\n<option value='{$row['name']}'>{$row['name']}</option>";
    }
    $dropdown .= "\r\n</select>";

?>
<form method="post" align= "right">
<table >
    <tr>
        <td>Select the Hub for which you want to add and area: </td>
        <td><?php echo $dropdown; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add" align= "right" /></td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

I want to display the same drop-down list in my page called `area_view.php` but the default value of the drop-down list must be equal to the selected value.

The variable in `area_index.php` used is  `$hub_name = $_POST['hub'];`

Comment: Well, that is covered by every HTML reference I've see so far for that HTML tag. What didn't work for you? Reading references? Start here and dig up what's in that tag allowed https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select

Answer (score 2):

Change your while loop to this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $dropdown .= "\r\n<option value='{$row['name']}'" . ($row['name'] == $_POST['hub'] ? "selected" : "") . ">{$row['name']}</option>";
}
```

This checks to see if the value you're passing as $_POST['hub'] from the previous page equals the value of $row['name'] for each option being added.  For the one that's equal, it will add the attribute `selected`, which will cause the browser to show that option as the selected one.